# unable to scan the ip address of Raspberry pi 3 B+ by using advance ip scanner

Tags: pi-3b+

I have connected the raspberry pi to the laptop without using Ethernet cable (I am getting power (5v) from the laptop). I have inserted a file in the SD card of Raspberry Pi for WiFi connection

```
country=IN
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev 
update_config=1
network={
       ssid="wifi  id"
       psk="password"
       key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Both laptop and raspberry pi have same WiFi. initially I got the ip address and it works fine. But now the advance ip scanner is not showing the raspberry pi's ip address. Can anyone help.

Comment: I suppose you want to access the RasPi from your laptop. If you do not use an ethernet cable, how do you connect? By WiFi? Is there another access point/router?

Comment: Chances are that the power provided by your laptops's usb port isn't sufficient. Try using a proper psu.

Comment: I have pasted a file( inside the file - WiFi id and password ) in the SD card .in this i have connected the raspberry pi.....initially it works fine but now advance ip scanner is not showing my rasp ip address